# The following packages have unmet dependencies: python-samba : Depends: samba-libs

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg

```
G50:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
sudo: unable to resolve host unknown-G50
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
software-center is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-samba : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: your problem appears to be `python-samba`. Did you try running `sudo apt-get -f install` as suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the error logs.. It says try

```
apt-get -f install
```

Add `sudo` to run it as admin. It'll solve the problem.